# Iterar array de objetos y sacarlos (eliminarlos) de uno por uno del array

Tags: php

Hola buenos días tengo un arreglo de objetos el cual quiero crear una función para que reciba el array e iterar para obtener el primer objeto, validar que la troncal no este vacía, si no esta vacía imprimirla para posteriormente sacar el objeto del array y así asarlo con cada uno de los objetos.

> Les comparto el array de objetos.

```
Array y función

    $prueba = array(
    Array ( 
            "troncal" => "2926", 
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Masterchannel SA de CV",
            "DIDS" => Array ( 
                525512042400), 
            "id_cdr" => "2926" 
    ), 
    Array ( 
            "troncal" => "2933", 
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Masterchannel SA de CV",
            "DIDS" => Array ( 
                525512042401), 
            "id_cdr" => "2926" 
    ), 
    Array ( 
            "troncal" => "2875", 
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Chacon & Rodriguez Asociados",
            "DIDS" => Array ( 
                525512090447), 
            "id_cdr" => "2875" 
    ), 
    Array ( 
            "troncal" => "2777", 
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Almacenaje y Distribucion Avior SA de CV",
            "DIDS" => Array ( 
                525546249183), 
            "id_cdr" => "2773" 
    ), 
    Array ( 
            "troncal" => "2876", 
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV",
            "DIDS" => Array (
                525512090445, 
                525526230587, 
                525552024342, 
                525552024546), 
            "id_cdr" => "2893" 
    ), 
    Array ( 
            "troncal" => "2878", 
            "nombre_cuenta" => "Dmg Mori Mexico SA de CV",
            "DIDS" => Array ( 
                528111070003), 
            "id_cdr" => "2878" 
    )
    );
    
    
function get_llamadas($data_cuentas){

    foreach ($data_cuentas as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value['troncal'])) {
            echo($value['troncal']);
        }
        // borro el registro del array
        unset($data_cuentas[$key]);
    }
}

?>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Da error? ¿Qué error? ¿No arroja los datos que esperas? ¿Qué datos esperas?

Comment: Tengo mi funcionalidad lista pero siempre hago preguntas para intentar mejorar mi código. En un momento mas lo comparto.

Comment: Ya, pero la función está vacía en tu pregunta, por lo tanto no podemos decirte: esto se puede mejorar así o asao... También veo confusión de conceptos en el planteamiento, si hay que leer directamente el primer elemento del array no hay que *iterar*  sobre él, sino simplemente acceder al índice `0` del mismo y hacer la comparación de lugar.

Comment: Listo ya coloque mi función al final del array, ¿Crees que el código este lo mas optimizado posible?

Comment: La pregunta es un poco confusa. ¿Qué significa *primer objeto*? Para mi es el primer elemento del array, pero luego hablas de *iterar*  y de eliminar elementos del array. ¿Lo que quieres es quitar aquellos elementos del array cuya clave `troncal` esté vacía?

Comment: Quiero iterar todo todo el array de objetos, obtener el primero array y validar que no este vacío el dato "troncal", si no esta vacío imprimirlo de lo contrario que no haga nada y finalmente eliminar el primer array y así hacerlo con cada uno de los arrays que se encuentran dentro del array principal. Ya tengo la funcionalidad jalando pero me gusta pedir ayuda para que siempre hacerlo de la mejor manera y optima posible. Espero que me vayas entendido

Comment: No te entiendo. ¿Por qué quieres iterar todo el array si sólo te interesa trabajar con el primero? ¿Por qué no vas directo al primero sin tener que iterarlo todo?

Comment: Puse como ejemplo el primero pero en realidad me interesa hacer lo mismo con todos es por eso que lo itero completo

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, si el array original tiene que ser modificado, tienes que pasarlo como referencia a la función (esto se hace anteponiendo `&` en la declaración del parámetro). Así, PHP asume que el `unset` se aplicará sobre el elemento original.

Luego, la lógica de tu función es incomprensible, lo mismo que el planteamiento de la pregunta. Parecería que lo que necesitas es eliminar los elementos del array cuyo valor `troncal` esté vacío.

Si es eso, podrías resolverlo así:

```
#Usamos & para pasar por referencia
function get_llamadas(&$data_cuentas){
    foreach ($data_cuentas as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value['troncal'])) {
            echo $value['troncal'].PHP_EOL;
        #Falta un else, o se eliminarían todos    
        }else{
            // borro el registro del array
            unset($data_cuentas[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```